# How to set an SPSS model nugget to be automatically placed on palette only?

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

This is a very very trivial question. However, it's impossible to find the answer online so far.

Allow me to describe what happens -

In SPSS Modeler, when a model (CHAID in this case) is run, it generates a nugget and the nugget is automatically placed on the stream, connected with the CHAID model and the node upstream. In addition, this nugget will appear in the palette on the right hand side of the window.

What I want to do -

I would like the nugget not to be placed in the stream and only appear in the palette.

What the problem is -

I have noticed in the past that the nugget created sometimes are placed in the palette only, sometimes in both the palette and the stream. I don't know what is controlling this behavior, and changing a couple of items in the "User Options" didn't seem to help.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've found out the answer to my own question. I'll put it here just in case somebody else may find it useful (though it turned out to be quite trivial).

In Modeler 15, the setting is done in "User Options" by the check box "Add Model to Stream".

In Modeler 16, the above doesn't not work (even this option exists). The real control is in "Stream Properties".